# How to update source codes of a phonegap application from server

Tags: javascript, cordova

I have been developing phonegap applications that need to make updates oftenly. The problem is pushing a new ipa to iTune Store take too long. So, I uploaded the application source codes(minified javascript) to my server and download it from application and "eval"  the minified js files. But i feel using eval has limitations and also not the right way. So, can someone tell me the right way to accomplish this. 
thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I'd love to have something like this as well. You're already ahead of me w/your eval() approach - but I'd have the same concerns as you there. Here's what I'm aware is out there on this topic - hope this helps?

### [IdeaPress(?)](http://ideapress.me/)

I just recently caught wind of this one - not sure how feasible but [it claims to do exactly what we'd like](http://ideanotion.net/phonegaps-ability-dynamically-updating-mobile-app/). I have to say the main site looks a bit flaky but I will definitly be checking this out to see if it's feasible or not.

### [HockeyApp?](http://hockeyapp.net/features/)

HockeyApp (possibly dead-end now). I thought there used to be a pretty clear solution for PhoneGap devs to integrate the HockeyApp API/feature set with their mobile apps but a recent Google search on this is turning up much less than I would think - so maybe it's a dead end now? http://goo.gl/GQOv5o

### [org.apache.cordova.file](http://goo.gl/86Af1H)

This requires more work and I haven't pushed far enough yet to see if it truly could be a means of updating the app post-app-store-deployment. But based on [what I've read](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/updating-ionic-apps-on-the-fly/1577/7) if you're just updating code for your WebView you shouldn't have to worry about App Store rejection or anything. [Related tutorial](http://goo.gl/NtqWh6)

### [Testflight App Testing (Apple)](http://goo.gl/H4kWqN)

I haven't gotten to play w/this yet but sounds like it could be promising for at least the beta/testing phase of development. I, like you, need a solution for end-users, not app testers, but I'll still be looking into this soon as it might replace me having to maintain my own over-the-air app installs for the best/testing periods.